# Base64 Stream receive truncated

Tags: php, jquery, base64

When i post a base64 stream to a php page using post, i never received the totality of the stream. I increase the max post size, but it doesn't affect anything.

Have you already seen a similar problem ?

Here is the server code :

```
$value = $_POST['file'];

echo "-------";
echo $value;
echo "-------";

$img = $value;
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

I'm not PHP developer, you will probably find some bad practices.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help / suggestions.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: provide your simplified code...

Comment: Sure, i'm sorry i forgot it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have suhosin check for the [suhosin.post.max_value_length](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.post.max_value_length)

Comment: Not sure if i can write it like that : echo suhosin.post.max_value_length;

I set the max post size to 40M in a php.ini file.

Comment: if you have suhosin installed, look for a file named suhosin.ini.

Comment: I do not have something like that.

Comment: you can check it with `php -v`, if there is something similar to: `with Suhosin v...`, there must be somewhere